# Segment Status Handling: NumAttempts WaitInterval params

Tags: sabre

At [this documentation](http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/ServicesPlatform/SP_Developer_Guide_v3.5.0.pdf) at page 15 of 22 it gives example:

```
<EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
    <OTA_AirBookRQ>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="NN"/>
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
            <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2014-06-03T12:30:00" FlightNumber="1022" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="F" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LAS"/>
                <MarketingAirline Code="AA" FlightNumber="1022"/>
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="DFW"/>
            </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="2" WaitInterval="100"/>
    </OTA_AirBookRQ>
</EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

Could you help me understand if I set such parameters for `NumAttempts` and `WaitInterval` what I am missing.

I could guess that I will have quick answer for segments with no halt on status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `OTA_AirBook` `HaltOnStatus` and `RedisplayReservation` work together. Basically, behind the scenes, the service will book what you requested and will attempt to redisplay the reservation up to `NumAttempts` times, waiting `WaitInterval` milliseconds between each check.

Each time it will look if the status of the segments in the itinerary changed, and it will validate them against what `<HaltOnStatus Code="NN"/>` has, (there can be several `<HaltOnStatus Code="NN"/>`). At least for **NN** it will keep on checking, for other ones like **UC** it will get out of the loop.

The reason is that NN is Sabre waiting for the airline's response on the booking request, and (I believe) anything else would be considered their response, so it leaves the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the given doc link, it says also "Some carriers can actually
take up to seven seconds to respond to a sell message", so do I miss that carrier response by setting very low values for those parameters?

Comment: You may set a "small" WaitInterval, like 1500 milliseconds and increase the NumAttempts to cover this.