# Creating PNR with SOAP webservices in SABRE

Tags: php, web-services, api, soap, sabre

i'm trying to create a new Booking using OTa Sabre Webservices, in some cases i got my ItineraryRef, but in some other cases i got a Warning from EnhancedAirBook, btw i order to complete booking i use this workflow, BargainFinderMax + EnhancedAirBook + PassengerDetails

In this particular case i'm trying to Book for two ADTS, can some body tell me or at least be light in darkness for me.

Thank you!

Request to EnhancedAirBook:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
        <From>
            <PartyId>sample.url.of.sabre.client.com</PartyId>
        </From>
        <To>
            <PartyId>webservices.sabre.com</PartyId>
        </To>
        <CPAId>7TZA</CPAId>
        <ConversationId>convId</ConversationId>
        <Service>EnhancedAirBookRQ</Service>
        <Action>EnhancedAirBookRQ</Action>
        <MessageData>
            <MessageId>1000</MessageId>
            <Timestamp>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</Timestamp>
            <TimeToLive>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</TimeToLive>
        </MessageData>
    </MessageHeader>
    <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
        <BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="Base64Binary" valueType="String">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</BinarySecurityToken>
    </Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2" HaltOnError="false" version="3.2.0">
        <OTA_AirBookRQ>
            <OriginDestinationInformation>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-13T13:02:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-13T11:52:00" FlightNumber="69" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="69" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-13T15:53:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-13T14:15:00" FlightNumber="8372" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="PTY" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="8372" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-19T06:40:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-19T05:10:00" FlightNumber="8371" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="8371" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="PTY" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-19T11:07:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-19T08:08:00" FlightNumber="66" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="66" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
        </OTA_AirBookRQ>
        <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
            <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
                <OptionalQualifiers>
                    <PricingQualifiers>
                        <ItineraryOptions>
                            <SegmentSelect Number="1" RPH="1" />
                            <SegmentSelect Number="2" RPH="2" />
                            <SegmentSelect Number="3" RPH="3" />
                            <SegmentSelect Number="4" RPH="4" />
                        </ItineraryOptions>
                        <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="2" />
                    </PricingQualifiers>
                </OptionalQualifiers>
            </PriceRequestInformation>
        </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
            <RedisplayReservation WaitInterval="2000" />
        </PostProcessing>
        <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false" />
    </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

**Response from EnhancedAirBook:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
        <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:From>
        <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">sample.url.of.sabre.client.com</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:To>
        <eb:CPAId>7TZA</eb:CPAId>
        <eb:ConversationId>convId</eb:ConversationId>
        <eb:Service>EnhancedAirBookRQ</eb:Service>
        <eb:Action>EnhancedAirBookRS</eb:Action>
        <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>1lsj6e9zy</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2017-04-13T02:22:10</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1000</eb:RefToMessageId>
        </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap-env:Header>
<soap-env:Body>
    <EnhancedAirBookRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
        <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
            <Success timeStamp="2017-04-12T21:22:10.870-05:00" />
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-12T21:22:08.607-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">NO COMBINABLE FARES FOR CLASS USED53</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
        </ApplicationResults>
        <OTA_AirBookRS>
            <OriginDestinationOption>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="04-13T13:02" DepartureDateTime="04-13T11:52" FlightNumber="0069" NumberInParty="002" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN" eTicket="true">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="0069" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="04-13T15:53" DepartureDateTime="04-13T14:15" FlightNumber="8372" NumberInParty="002" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN" eTicket="true">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="PTY" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="8372" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="04-19T06:40" DepartureDateTime="04-19T05:10" FlightNumber="8371" NumberInParty="002" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN" eTicket="true">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="8371" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="PTY" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="04-19T11:07" DepartureDateTime="04-19T08:08" FlightNumber="0066" NumberInParty="002" ResBookDesigCode="T" Status="NN" eTicket="true">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="0066" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOG" />
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationOption>
        </OTA_AirBookRS>
        <TravelItineraryReadRS>
            <TravelItinerary>
                <CustomerInfo />
                <ItineraryInfo>
                    <ReservationItems>
                        <Item RPH="1">
                            <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0636" ArrivalDateTime="04-13T13:02" DayOfWeekInd="4" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-13T11:52" ElapsedTime="02.10" FlightNumber="0069" NumberInParty="02" ResBookDesigCode="T" SegmentNumber="0001" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="UC" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="false">
                                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOG" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1" />
                                <Equipment AirEquipType="321" />
                                <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="0069" />
                                <Meal Code="S" />
                                <OperatingAirline Code="AV" CompanyShortName="/AVIANCA" />
                                <OriginLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                                <SupplierRef ID="DCAV" />
                                <Text>OPERATED BY /AVIANCA</Text>
                                <UpdatedArrivalTime>04-13T13:02</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                                <UpdatedDepartureTime>04-13T11:52</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                            </FlightSegment>
                        </Item>
                        <Item RPH="2">
                            <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0468" ArrivalDateTime="04-13T15:53" DayOfWeekInd="4" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-13T14:15" ElapsedTime="01.38" FlightNumber="8372" NumberInParty="02" ResBookDesigCode="T" SegmentNumber="0002" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="UC" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="false">
                                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="PTY" />
                                <Equipment AirEquipType="320" />
                                <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="8372" />
                                <Meal Code="S" />
                                <OperatingAirline Code="AV" CompanyShortName="/AEROGAL" />
                                <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOG" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1" />
                                <SupplierRef ID="DCAV" />
                                <Text>OPERATED BY /AEROGAL</Text>
                                <UpdatedArrivalTime>04-13T15:53</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                                <UpdatedDepartureTime>04-13T14:15</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                            </FlightSegment>
                        </Item>
                        <Item RPH="3">
                            <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0468" ArrivalDateTime="04-19T06:40" DayOfWeekInd="3" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-19T05:10" ElapsedTime="01.30" FlightNumber="8371" NumberInParty="02" ResBookDesigCode="T" SegmentNumber="0003" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="UC" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="false">
                                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BOG" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1" />
                                <Equipment AirEquipType="320" />
                                <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="8371" />
                                <Meal Code="S" />
                                <OperatingAirline Code="AV" CompanyShortName="/AEROGAL" />
                                <OriginLocation LocationCode="PTY" />
                                <SupplierRef ID="DCAV" />
                                <Text>OPERATED BY /AEROGAL</Text>
                                <UpdatedArrivalTime>04-19T06:40</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                                <UpdatedDepartureTime>04-19T05:10</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                            </FlightSegment>
                        </Item>
                        <Item RPH="4">
                            <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0636" ArrivalDateTime="04-19T11:07" DayOfWeekInd="3" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-19T08:08" ElapsedTime="01.59" FlightNumber="0066" NumberInParty="02" ResBookDesigCode="T" SegmentNumber="0004" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="UC" StopQuantity="00" eTicket="false">
                                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                                <Equipment AirEquipType="321" />
                                <MarketingAirline Code="AV" FlightNumber="0066" />
                                <Meal Code="S" />
                                <OperatingAirline Code="AV" CompanyShortName="/AVIANCA" />
                                <OriginLocation LocationCode="BOG" Terminal="TERMINAL 1" TerminalCode="1" />
                                <SupplierRef ID="DCAV" />
                                <Text>OPERATED BY /AVIANCA</Text>
                                <UpdatedArrivalTime>04-19T11:07</UpdatedArrivalTime>
                                <UpdatedDepartureTime>04-19T08:08</UpdatedDepartureTime>
                            </FlightSegment>
                        </Item>
                    </ReservationItems>
                </ItineraryInfo>
                <ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1S">
                    <Source PseudoCityCode="4Q0H" />
                </ItineraryRef>
            </TravelItinerary>
        </TravelItineraryReadRS>
    </EnhancedAirBookRS>
</soap-env:Body>
```

Then when i call PassengerDetails with this

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
        <From>
            <PartyId>sample.url.of.sabre.client.com</PartyId>
        </From>
        <To>
            <PartyId>webservices.sabre.com</PartyId>
        </To>
        <CPAId>7TZA</CPAId>
        <ConversationId>convId</ConversationId>
        <Service>PassengerDetailsRQ</Service>
        <Action>PassengerDetailsRQ</Action>
        <MessageData>
            <MessageId>1000</MessageId>
            <Timestamp>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</Timestamp>
            <TimeToLive>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</TimeToLive>
        </MessageData>
    </MessageHeader>
    <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
        <BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="Base64Binary" valueType="String">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</BinarySecurityToken>
    </Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3" version="3.3.0">
        <PostProcessing>
            <EndTransactionRQ>
                <EndTransaction Ind="true" />
                <Source ReceivedFrom="TARA TESTING" />
            </EndTransactionRQ>
        </PostProcessing>
        <PriceQuoteInfo>
            <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1" />
            <Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="1" />
        </PriceQuoteInfo>
        <SpecialReqDetails>
            <AddRemarkRQ>
                <RemarkInfo>
                    <FOP_Remark Type="CASH" />
                    <Remark Type="General">
                        <Text>TEST GENERAL REMARK</Text>
                    </Remark>
                </RemarkInfo>
            </AddRemarkRQ>
            <SpecialServiceRQ>
                <SpecialServiceInfo>
                    <AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="A">
                        <Document ExpirationDate="2018-05-26" Number="288282822" Type="P">
                            <IssueCountry>VE</IssueCountry>
                            <NationalityCountry>VE</NationalityCountry>
                        </Document>
                        <PersonName DateOfBirth="1989-01-20" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1" DocumentHolder="true">
                            <GivenName>Mariscal</GivenName>
                            <Surname>De Campo</Surname>
                        </PersonName>
                        <VendorPrefs>
                            <Airline Hosted="false" />
                        </VendorPrefs>
                    </AdvancePassenger>
                    <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                        <PersonName DateOfBirth="1979-01-20" Gender="M" NameNumber="2.1">
                            <GivenName>Mariscal</GivenName>
                            <Surname>De Guertra</Surname>
                        </PersonName>
                        <VendorPrefs>
                            <Airline Hosted="false" />
                        </VendorPrefs>
                    </SecureFlight>
                </SpecialServiceInfo>
            </SpecialServiceRQ>
        </SpecialReqDetails>
        <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
            <AgencyInfo>
                <Address>
                    <AddressLine>DIRECCION</AddressLine>
                    <CityName>CARACAS</CityName>
                    <CountryCode>VE</CountryCode>
                    <PostalCode>1071</PostalCode>
                    <StateCountyProv StateCode="MI" />
                    <StreetNmbr>OFIC 18</StreetNmbr>
                    <VendorPrefs>
                        <Airline Hosted="true" />
                    </VendorPrefs>
                </Address>
                <Ticketing TicketType="7TAW" />
            </AgencyInfo>
            <CustomerInfo>
                <ContactNumbers>
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="KTM" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="H" />
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="KTM" NameNumber="2.1" Phone="817-777-1212" PhoneUseType="H" />
                </ContactNumbers>
                <Email Address="churromorales20@gmail.com" NameNumber="1.1" />
                <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT">
                    <GivenName>Mariscal</GivenName>
                    <Surname>De Campo</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <PersonName NameNumber="2.1" PassengerType="ADT">
                    <GivenName>Mariscal</GivenName>
                    <Surname>De Guertra</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </CustomerInfo>
        </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
    </PassengerDetailsRQ>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I got this response showing this warning **WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE - CHECK ITINERARY** I think this error comes from the fact that there was a problem in the first call to EnhancedAirBook

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
        <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:From>
        <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">sample.url.of.sabre.client.com</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:To>
        <eb:CPAId>7TZA</eb:CPAId>
        <eb:ConversationId>convId</eb:ConversationId>
        <eb:Service>PassengerDetailsRQ</eb:Service>
        <eb:Action>PassengerDetailsRS</eb:Action>
        <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>qpmyhopy9</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2017-04-13T02:22:12</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1000</eb:RefToMessageId>
        </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap-env:Header>
<soap-env:Body>
    <PassengerDetailsRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
        <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
            <Success timeStamp="2017-04-12T21:22:12.201-05:00" />
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-12T21:22:12.048-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">CHECK ITINERARY</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-12T21:22:12.125-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">ÂPQ RECORD NUMBER NOT VALIDÂ</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-12T21:22:12.156-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">ÂPQ RECORD NUMBER NOT VALIDÂ</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-12T21:22:12.199-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">*IM AND CANCEL UNABLE SEGMENTS</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
        </ApplicationResults>
    </PassengerDetailsRS>
</soap-env:Body>
```

I really hope anyone can help me, thanks for your time.

**EDIT 13/04/2017**

I have changed my request to EnhancedAirBook, i have added HaltOnStatus tags, like suggest Wisdoom in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247511/segment-status-handling-numattempts-waitinterval-params/42250758#42250758)

**Request to EnhancedAirBook:**

```
<EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2" HaltOnError="false" version="3.2.0">
        <OTA_AirBookRQ>
            <HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
            <HaltOnStatus Code="LL" />
            <HaltOnStatus Code="UN" />
            <HaltOnStatus Code="NO" />
            <HaltOnStatus Code="HL" />
            <OriginDestinationInformation>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-13T19:03:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-13T15:26:00" FlightNumber="914" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="N" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="MIA" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AA" FlightNumber="914" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-14T11:23:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-14T06:25:00" FlightNumber="148" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="N" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="JFK" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AA" FlightNumber="148" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="MIA" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-19T09:37:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-19T06:30:00" FlightNumber="2230" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="N" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="MIA" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AA" FlightNumber="2230" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="JFK" />
                </FlightSegment>
                <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-04-19T14:31:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-04-19T11:04:00" FlightNumber="979" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="N" Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CCS" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="AA" FlightNumber="979" />
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="MIA" />
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
            <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="10" WaitInterval="500" />
        </OTA_AirBookRQ>
        <OTA_AirPriceRQ>
            <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
                <OptionalQualifiers>
                    <PricingQualifiers>
                        <ItineraryOptions>
                            <SegmentSelect Number="1" RPH="1" />
                            <SegmentSelect Number="2" RPH="2" />
                            <SegmentSelect Number="3" RPH="3" />
                            <SegmentSelect Number="4" RPH="4" />
                        </ItineraryOptions>
                        <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="2" />
                    </PricingQualifiers>
                </OptionalQualifiers>
            </PriceRequestInformation>
        </OTA_AirPriceRQ>
        <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false">
            <RedisplayReservation WaitInterval="500" />
        </PostProcessing>
        <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false" />
    </EnhancedAirBookRQ>
```

**And this is the response:**

```
<EnhancedAirBookRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
        <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
            <Success timeStamp="2017-04-13T12:21:46.907-05:00" />
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-13T12:21:45.187-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">UNABLE 00 AVAILABLE</Message>
                    <Message code="0293">UNABLE 00 AVAILABLE</Message>
                    <Message code="0118">SYSTEM UNABLE TO PROCESS</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="Application" timeStamp="2017-04-13T12:21:45.774-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">No PNR in AAA, caused by [No PNR in AAA, code: 500306, severity: WARNING]</Message>
                    <Message code="700408">No PNR in AAA, caused by [No PNR in AAA, code: 500306, severity: WARNING]</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-13T12:21:46.348-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">FORMAT, CHECK SEGMENT NUMBER-0003</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="Application" timeStamp="2017-04-13T12:21:46.905-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">No PNR in AAA, caused by [No PNR in AAA, code: 500306, severity: WARNING]</Message>
                    <Message code="700408">No PNR in AAA, caused by [No PNR in AAA, code: 500306, severity: WARNING]</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
        </ApplicationResults>
    </EnhancedAirBookRS>
```

Thanks to everyone who take 5 mins lo read this questions, i need to solve this issue with my Travel Tool, the support from Sabre it's really bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into using CreatePassengerNameRQ, which simplifies even more the consumption and more advanced error handling.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/

Answer (score 2):

For the `NO COMBINABLE FARES FOR CLASS USED`, that is because you tried to price an itinerary that could not be priced.

When you request NN, that request is sent to the airline, so before they respond you don't have a confirmed itinerary, which is a requirement for most fares and that is likely the situation here.

Now, if you see the service response, you'll see that the status all segments have is UC, which is unable to confirm. This would trigger another error at the time of pricing, something line `UC STATUS NOT ALLOWED`.

Please check what I mentioned about HaltOnStatus in this other thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42250758/3701641

The `CHECK ITINERARY` error is likely related to the same situation, the UC status on the itinerary.

Comment: Hello Wisdoom, i have changed my request to EnhancedAirBook using HaltOnStatus in order to wait airline response, may i share with you this new information trough pastebin?? Or may be i need to edit may question?? In this case i'm getting other errors...

Comment: If you are getting other errors, then it might be better to ask another question with that error.